# Xenial - USB NICs keep losing connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, usb, network-manager, ethernet

I have a Dell XPS 13 with a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Two different USB3.0 gigabit ethernet adapters have gotten into the habit of dropping connections. Every so often, randomly, I'll see a toast notification saying 'Disconnected - Ethernet network'. A couple of seconds later the connection restores.

I've checked /var/log/syslog and this is roughly what happens when the connection drops:

```
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.921495] usb 2-2.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.925240] usb 2-2.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.925563] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.929257] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -71
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv6 with address fe80::3774:7c02:9a8b:b1c0.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS dhclient[834]: receive_packet failed on enx000ec6d95deb: Network is down
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.932994] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -71
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv4 with address x.x.x.7.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3774:7c02:9a8b:b1c0 on enx000ec6d95deb.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Withdrawing address record for x.x.x.7 on enx000ec6d95deb.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.4852] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:03] offline
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:03] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.981336] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -71
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.984834] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -71
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.5189] dhcp4 (enx000ec6d95deb): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 834
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.5189] dhcp4 (enx000ec6d95deb): state changed bound -> done
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.5195] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS dnsmasq[2990]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.988332] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -71
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.991798] usb 2-2.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.5262] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9360.995346] usb 2-2.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS dbus[1106]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <error> [1503573723.5410] platform-linux: do-change-link[17]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <warn>  [1503573723.5411] device (enx000ec6d95deb): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573723.5413] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/net/enx000ec6d95deb, iface: enx000ec6d95deb)
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS dbus[1106]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enx000ec6d95deb]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enx000ec6d95deb]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 24 12:22:03 myXPS kernel: [ 9361.326473] usb 2-2.1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <warn>  [1503573724.2196] device (eth0): failed to find device 18 'eth0' with udev
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS kernel: [ 9361.685978] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0e:c6:d9:5d:eb
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.2228] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/17)
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS kernel: [ 9361.705535] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: renamed from eth0
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.2552] device (eth0): interface index 18 renamed iface from 'eth0' to 'enx000ec6d95deb'
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.2687] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/net/enx000ec6d95deb, iface: enx000ec6d95deb)
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.2687] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/net/enx000ec6d95deb, iface: enx000ec6d95deb): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.2689] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS kernel: [ 9361.737072] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx000ec6d95deb: link is not ready
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS kernel: [ 9362.066985] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx000ec6d95deb: link is not ready
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.6013] keyfile: add connection in-memory (e80c5f07-2a56-3e0f-9737-c194012945bb,"Wired connection 1")
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573724.6022] settings: (enx000ec6d95deb): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Aug 24 12:22:04 myXPS kernel: [ 9362.322105] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS kernel: [ 9365.650199] ax88179_178a 2-2.1:1.0 enx000ec6d95deb: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.1919] device (enx000ec6d95deb): link connected
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS kernel: [ 9365.658349] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx000ec6d95deb: link becomes ready
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.1952] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.1992] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2052] device (enx000ec6d95deb): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (e80c5f07-2a56-3e0f-9737-c194012945bb)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2095] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2102] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2120] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2134] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2182] dhcp4 (enx000ec6d95deb): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.2243] dhcp4 (enx000ec6d95deb): dhclient started with pid 1061
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dhclient[1061]: DHCPREQUEST of x.x.x.7 on enx000ec6d95deb to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x217dca36)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dhclient[1061]: DHCPACK of x.x.x.7 from x.x.x.1
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3131]   address x.x.x.7
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3131]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3132]   gateway x.x.x.1
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3132]   server identifier x.x.x.21
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3132]   lease time 691200
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3133]   nameserver '8.8.8.8'
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3133]   nameserver '8.8.4.4'
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv4 with address x.x.x.7.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3133] dhcp4 (enx000ec6d95deb): state changed unknown -> bound
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dhclient[1061]: bound to x.x.x.7 -- renewal in 284726 seconds.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: New relevant interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Registering new address record for x.x.x.7 on enx000ec6d95deb.IPv4.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3271] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3282] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3287] device (enx000ec6d95deb): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3289] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:08] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3346] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3347] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enx000ec6d95deb) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3350] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dnsmasq[2990]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dnsmasq[2990]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53(via enx000ec6d95deb)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS dnsmasq[2990]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53(via enx000ec6d95deb)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1503573728.3492] device (enx000ec6d95deb): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [enx000ec6d95deb]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [enx000ec6d95deb]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:08] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/17
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:08] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/17
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:08] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/17
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 24 12:22:08 myXPS systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 24 12:22:09 myXPS whoopsie[1309]: [12:22:09] online
Aug 24 12:22:09 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv6 with address fe80::3774:7c02:9a8b:b1c0.
Aug 24 12:22:09 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: New relevant interface enx000ec6d95deb.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug 24 12:22:09 myXPS avahi-daemon[1150]: Registering new address record for fe80::3774:7c02:9a8b:b1c0 on enx000ec6d95deb.*.
```

The current NIC is a Ugreen USB3.0 gigabit adapter. On the Amazon page, they list Linux support and the they do indeed work out of the box. When this started happening, I downloaded the drivers from Ugreen's website, built them and installed the kernel module, which is in use:

```
rob@myXPS:~/Downloads/LINUX/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.18.0_SOURCE$
lsmod | grep ax88179 ax88179_178a           24576  0 usbnet           
45056  2 ax88179_178a,cdc_ether mii                    16384  2
usbnet,ax88179_178a
```

However, the driver appears to have made no difference. I have also had this happen with a TP Link USB3.0 gigabit adapter, although I did not install the TP Link drivers for that one.

The NIC is plugged into a powered USB3.0 hub built into my monitor. I am running 4.10.0-32-generic AMD64.

Side note: as I've just bought 20 of these Ugreen adapters for the office, I need to know I haven't bought lemons!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try disabling power saving in Network Manager to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It may take a reboot.

Any improvement?

Comment: I've done this, however the only config file in that directory relates to the wifi. Restarted Network-Manager, will see if it makes a difference. Thanks for the reply.